# 'newacc' is not a class or a name space

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, method-call

Hey guys I'm fairly new to OOP and c++ in general so please bear with me.

I'm trying to define a class, it's functions, and then use them. I'll show what I have so far and where I'm encountering errors.

In a file called "account.h" I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Account{
string fname;
string lname;
string sinnum;
string accttype;
int numtrans;
double balance;

public:
Account(string,string,string,string);
double DepositAmt(double);
double WithdrawAmt(double);
void PrintStatement();
void getFinalBalance();
};
```

In a file called "account.cpp" I have:

```
Account::Account(string firstname, string lastname, string sinnumber, string acc
{
fname = firstname;
lname = lastname;
sinnum = sinnumber;
accttype = accounttype;
numtrans = 0;
balance = 0;
}

double Account::DepositAmt(double deposit)
{
balance = balance + deposit;
return balance;
}

double Account::WithdrawAmt(double withdraw)
{
balance = balance - withdraw;
return balance;
}


void Account::PrintStatement()
{
cout << "First Name: " << fname << endl;
cout << "Last Name: " << lname << endl;
cout << "SIN: " << sinnum << endl;
cout << "Account Type: " << accttype << endl;
cout << "Total Transactions: " << numtrans << endl;
cout << "Final balance: $" << balance << endl;
}

void Account::getFinalBalance()
{
cout << "Your Final balance is: $" << balance << endl;
}
```

And finally in my last file called "ass2012.cpp" I have:

```
#include "account.h"
#include "account.cpp"

int main()
{
string fname, lname, sinnum, accttype;
int tempaccttype;


cout << "\nPlease enter your last name: " << endl;
cin >> lname;
cout << "\nPlease enter your SIN number: " << endl;
cin >> sinnum;
cout << "\nPlease choose your account type: "<< endl;
cout << "1: Checking" << endl;
cout << "2: Savings" << endl;
cin >> tempaccttype;

if (tempaccttype == 1)
{
 accttype = "Checking";
}
else
{
 accttype = "Savings";
}

Account newacc (fname, lname, sinnum, accttype); // HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
newacc::getFinalStatement();
return 0;
}
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong!!

EDIT: Thanks Naveen!! It's always the little things that run me up the wall.

Answer (score 5):

For calling methods on objects you should use `.` operator and not `::` operator i.e. you should do `newacc.getFinalBalance()`(Note that method name was also wrong, I corrected it here).

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about C++ and programming in general, I too am a novice. But I would change the line newacc::getFinalStatement(); to newacc.getFinalStatement();. If this doesn't work I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

the general synatx are:

```
Objectname.memberfunction();     //public
Objectname.datzmember               //public
classname::staticmembers         //public
```

:: is scope resolution operator and used only when there is a scope ambiguity. else there s np need to use it. its good to use it as a programming practice though.